# How to do multithreading or multiprocessing while calling function in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have sample dictionary is below

- I need to find the count of each attribute
- I need to implement using multithreading
- total(todos) is the main function. In this there are 3 other functions called. which i need to implement using multithreading. Right now first it will do sequentially like first it will do userid_count(todos) followed by title_count(todos) and complete_count(todos). Since each of these function is independent of each other I need to do with multithreading/multiprocessing

```
    todos = [{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'A', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'B ', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'C', 'completed': False},
     {'userId': 1, 'id': 2, 'title': 'A', 'completed': True},
     {'userId': 2, 'id': 1,'title': 'B', 'completed': False}]
    def total(todos):
        user_count = userid_count(todos)
        ###### Multithreading need to implement ##########
        title = title_count(todos)
        completed = complete_count(todos)
        search_count_all = {**user_count, **title, **completed}
        return search_count_all
    
    def userid_count(todos)
        #return userid count there are 2 user id 1, 2
        #{"userid":2}
        pass
    def title_count(todos)
        #return title count there are 3 title A, B, C
        #{"title":3}
        pass
    def complete_count(todos)
        #return completed count there are Tru and False
        #{"True": 1, "False":3}
        pass
    
    total(todos)
```

Expected out is
`[{"userid":2},{"title":3},{"True": 1, "False":3} ]`

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? It's OK if it is, we just need to know because there's *really* no point in doing multi-threading or multiprocessing for this problem, it's almost certainly going to make your program more complicated and slower.

Comment: @Blckknght its not homework problem, i made it is smaller my actual scenario is working  high volume of data. So each function is taking some time so i need to try using multithreading once

Comment: Because of the GIL, multithreaded code in Python doesn't *ever* run in parallel. At best it can let you do multiple IO-limited tasks interleaved (like reading data from several network connections into memory). For a CPU-limited task (like counting something in memory), it's just overhead. Multiprocessing *can* run things in parallel on different CPUs on your system. But there's a lot of overhead, since all the data you need the code to process needs to be copied between the processes. Often that overhead is greater than what you save by parallel processing.

Comment: @Blckknght, you mean to say that there is no way to run each function in parallel even if they are independent of each other.  Sryy for asking questions not good in parallel processing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using multithreading.

```
import threading, queue
user_count_result = queue.Queue()
title_count_result = queue.Queue()
complete_count_result = queue.Queue()
def total(todos):
    user_countThread = threading.Thread(target=userid_count,args=(todo,user_count_result,))
    titleThread = threading.Thread(target=title_count,args=(todo,title_count_result,))
    completedThread = threading.Thread(target=complete_count,args=(todo,complete_count_result,))

    user_countThread.start()
    titleThread.start()
    completedThread.start()

    user_countThread.join()
    titleThread.join()
    completedThread.join()


    search_count_all = {**user_count_result.get(), **title_count_result.get(), **complete_count_result.get()}
    return search_count_all

def userid_count(todos, user_count_result)
    #Your logic here
    user_count_result.put({"userid": 2})

    
def title_count(todos, title_count_result)
    #Your logic here
    title_count_result.put({"userid": 2})
    
def complete_count(todos, complete_count_result)
    #Your logic here
    complete_count_result.put({"userid": 2})
```

Comment: where are three functions >  user_count, title, completed

Comment: is the function name is  user_count_result, title_count_result, complete_count_result line number 3, 4, 5

Comment: I have updated the answer u can check it.

Comment: what is user_count_result.put({"userid": 2}) and line number 6 there is user_count_result . what it is mean

Comment: Whatever the result you wanna return from that function u can pass there.

Comment: line number 2 and line number six, can you please explain "user_count_result "

Comment: My user_count_result is None so it didnot execute succesfully